# Rmagick use transparent grey layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rmagick

I would like to add a grey transparent layer on top of my image using Rmagick. All I could get is a black opaque one.

Here is my best try:

```
bg = Magick::ImageList.new
open('http://static.lukew.com/dropdowns_effort.png', 'rb') do |f|
  bg.from_blob(f.read)
end

layer = Magick::Image.new(400, 400) {
  self.background_color = Magick::Pixel.new(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

layer.alpha(Magick::ActivateAlphaChannel)
layer.opacity  = 0.5

bg.each do |frame|
  frame.composite!(layer, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  frame.strip!
end
bg.write
```

here is what I get [image] while I'd like to get this [image]

Since this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284637/rmagick-transparency-not-working-when-compositing-one-image-over-another) suggests that this might be dependent of the environment, I'm using a mac running Yosemite.